# C Macro to convert a string to a pascal string type

Tags: c, macros

I would like some ideas for a macro to convert a preprocessor defined string to a pascal type string and then be able to use the macro to initialize const char arrays and the like.

Something like this would be great:

```
#define P_STRING_CONV(str) ...???...

const char *string = P_STRING_CONV("some string");

struct
{
    char str[30];
    ...
}some_struct = {.str = P_STRING_CONV("some_other_string")};
```

I already tried something like this:

```
#define DEFINE_PASCAL_STRING(var, str, strlen) struct {uint8_t len; char content[strlen-1];} (var) = {sizeof(str)-1, (str)}
```

(The strlen parameter could be removed, but I need a defined size.)

That works fine, but cannot be used to initialize elements in a struct. And for const char arrays I need to cast it to some other variable.

Any great ideas?

Comment: 1. Why are you trying to do this? I think that I don't really understand what is it that you actually want to achieve.

Comment: The major problem is that you seem to think Pascal-like string would be compatible with C strings (pointers to `char`, or arrays of `char`), which it can't really be naturally. What is the problem using Pascal-like string would solve? Why do you want to use them?

Comment: At the very least, the strings should keep a NUL terminator, so reducing their max length to 254 chars. At least then you could use them as const arguments by passing  [address+1].

Comment: I need to communicate with a system that uses Pascal like strings, that is the only reason for using it.

It is also just for making the code easier to understand. Right now a have to have a function to initialize some variables and for const I need something like `const char string[30] = "\004test";`

Comment: Hmm.. I think I would have gone for a 'PasStr' type and  'CtoPasStr()' and PasToCstr() style 'conversion' functions, even if that requires malloc/free-style string memory management to avoid 1-byte overruns and the like.

Comment: BTW, clang does this with the `-fpascal-strings` compiler flag and a special `"\p"` prefix. Example: `"\ptest"` will prefix the string with 0x4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the macro into two:

```
#define PASCAL_STRING_TYPE(size) struct { unsigned char len; char content[(size) - 1]; }
#define PASCAL_STRING_INIT(str) { .len = sizeof(str) - 1, .content = (str) }
```

Then use it like so:

```
static const PASCAL_STRING_TYPE(100) foo = PASCAL_STRING_INIT("foo");

struct bar {
   int answer;
   PASCAL_STRING_TYPE(100) question;
};
static const struct bar quux = {
    .answer = 42,
    .question = PASCAL_STRING_INIT("The Answer")
};
```

(Not tested.)

Comment: Good idea.
But i cannot have a `extern PASCAL_STRING_TYPE(30) some_string;` because the compiler sees it as to different declarations which it thinks are incompatible.
But for statics it works as I need.

Comment: True, but you could do `typedef PASCAL_STRING_TYPE(30) pstr30;` and `extern pstr30 some_string;`.

Answer (score 2):

> to convert a string to a pascal string type

To convert a *string literal*, `_Generic` and *compound literal* will get close to OP objective.

For a better solution, more details and example use cases would help illustrate OP's goal.

```
#define P_STRING_CONV(X) _Generic((X)+0, \
  char *: &((struct {char len; char s[sizeof(X)-1]; }){ (char)(sizeof(X)-1), (X) }).len \
  )

void dump(const char *s) {
  unsigned length = (unsigned char) *s++;
  printf("L:%u \"", length);
  while (length--) {
    printf("%c", *s++);
  }
  printf("\"\n");
}

int main(void) {
  dump(P_STRING_CONV(""));
  dump(P_STRING_CONV("A"));
  dump(P_STRING_CONV("AB"));
  dump(P_STRING_CONV("ABC"));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
L:0 ""
L:1 "A"
L:2 "AB"
L:3 "ABC"
```

---

[@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961847/c-macro-to-convert-a-string-to-a-pascal-string-type/45966153?noredirect=1#comment78893884_45966153) recommended that the created pascal-like string also contain a terminating *null character*.  To do so with above code, simple change `sizeof(X)-1` into `sizeof(X)`.  Then by accessing the `pascal_like_string + 1`, code has a pointer to a valid C string.

---

`(X)+0` converts an array type to a pointer

`sizeof(X)-!!sizeof(X)` produces a size of the string literal, not counting its \0.  At least 1.

`struct {char len; char s[sizeof(X)-!!sizeof(X)]; }` Is a right-sized pascal-like structure.

`(struct {char len; char s[sizeof(X)-!!sizeof(X)]; }){ (char)(sizeof(X)-1), (X) }` is a *compound literal*.

---

The following will convert a C *string* to a pascal like string.  Note that as a pascal like string, there is no `'\0'`.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *pstring_convert(char *s) {
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  assert(len <= UCHAR_MAX);
  memmove(s+1, s, len);
  s[0] = (char) (unsigned char) len;
  return s;
}
```

Comment: To be useful in C, even a Pascal-type string needs to store a null terminator so it can be passed to functions that expect C strings, not Pascal strings.  Things like system calls, for example (`open()`, et al) demand it.  The majority of the C library expects C strings.  Having to copy the Pascal string to create a C string would be unnecessarily heavy-duty work.  You don't have to account for the null in the length byte (it's simply there; the length simply records the number of characters up to the null).  You do (IMNSHO) have to add it.  Knowing the length has important advantages.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Fair enough.  OP did comment "I need to communicate with a system that uses Pascal like strings" so this code does that.  I suspect OP needs some p-string constants. Had OP requested an object that worked both like a Pascal-like string and a C string, your idea is certainly valuable with the more flexible object. Note that conversion from C string to a common pascal_and_C like string incurs additional memory management issues not needed with only a pure C to/from pascal conversion.

Comment: I don't get the point of `sizeof(X)-!!sizeof(X)`. If `X` is a string literal, `sizeof(X)` will be at least 1 (even if `X` is `""`), so `!!sizeof(X)` will always be 1. But that means that if `X` is `""`, then the array will be declared as `s[0]`, which is not valid (although gcc accepts it).

Comment: I think it works as needed, but my compiler only support C89 and C99, and as I understand generics was introduced in C11. Correct me if i'm wrong. But anyway, it does not work with my compiler.

Comment: @rici Agreed that `sizeof(X)-1` is sufficient.  The `!!sizeof(X)` was an effect of how code was developed.

Comment: @Tajen Important information that would limit answers like "unable to use a compiler that conforms to the current standard and need a C.xxx solution" should be part of the post.