# Straight-Forward Polymorphism with C

Tags: c, function, polymorphism

Is it possible to make polymorphic functions with C where we don't have to use any classes or OOP type function calls in the main function?

Like, I want to make a function to return the minimum value among two integers or characters or strings.
I just want to call the function like `function_name(variable1, variable2)` in main function.

It is quite easy to do with C++ templates but is there any way to do it with C? I've gone through closely all "polymorphism with C" related questions and answers but couldn't find any clue.

Comment: Check out how e.g. `qsort()` does it. That’s what you can do. Apart from that there’s [`_Generic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) for type dispatch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C11 \_Generic usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096584/c11-generic-usage)

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski _Generic cannot differentiate char and int array, like for doing getting length of an array and a char array (string), it cannot be used. What to do in this case?

Comment: @Fuad, it's not possible to do all the things that a `C++` templates are doing for a simple reason that the templates are evaluated during semantic parsing, while macros are evaluated during preprocessing.

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski How you would write a function to get the length of an string or an array in c?

Comment: Statically allocated arrays are checked during compile-time, during semantic parsing. As for the dynamic arrays, as far as `C` compiler is concerned, they are pointers. A pointer points to a start of a memory location, and that's it, the length is unknown. The end of the location (the length) is determined by the developer  by writing code and by using some coding standards.

Comment: There is a standard for strings (which are pointers to arrays of `char`) that the end is at location that has `\0`, so counting the bytes until `\0` is reached will give you the answer. For other types, there are no standards. Even for `char *` you are not required to follow the standard if you don't use standard functions. You are free to write your own functions that will consider different standards (example `pascal` standard). `C` is low level language and the developer is free to define it's own memory organization.

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski Thank You, Nice Lead. Can you give me some standard working examples of writing functions that can do things like this?

Comment: check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45966153/2816703)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a `#define` can do what you want.

But it is hard and complicated to use. Take the max macro in linux for example:

From linux 5.12-rc2:*/include/linux/minmax.h*

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 */
#ifndef _LINUX_MINMAX_H
#define _LINUX_MINMAX_H

/*
 * min()/max()/clamp() macros must accomplish three things:
 *
 * - avoid multiple evaluations of the arguments (so side-effects like
 *   "x++" happen only once) when non-constant.
 * - perform strict type-checking (to generate warnings instead of
 *   nasty runtime surprises). See the "unnecessary" pointer comparison
 *   in __typecheck().
 * - retain result as a constant expressions when called with only
 *   constant expressions (to avoid tripping VLA warnings in stack
 *   allocation usage).
 */
#define __typecheck(x, y) \
    (!!(sizeof((typeof(x) *)1 == (typeof(y) *)1)))

/*
 * This returns a constant expression while determining if an argument is
 * a constant expression, most importantly without evaluating the argument.
 * Glory to Martin Uecker <Martin.Uecker@med.uni-goettingen.de>
 */
#define __is_constexpr(x) \
    (sizeof(int) == sizeof(*(8 ? ((void *)((long)(x) * 0l)) : (int *)8)))

#define __no_side_effects(x, y) \
        (__is_constexpr(x) && __is_constexpr(y))

#define __safe_cmp(x, y) \
        (__typecheck(x, y) && __no_side_effects(x, y))

#define __cmp(x, y, op) ((x) op (y) ? (x) : (y))

#define __cmp_once(x, y, unique_x, unique_y, op) ({ \
        typeof(x) unique_x = (x);       \
        typeof(y) unique_y = (y);       \
        __cmp(unique_x, unique_y, op); })

#define __careful_cmp(x, y, op) \
    __builtin_choose_expr(__safe_cmp(x, y), \
        __cmp(x, y, op), \
        __cmp_once(x, y, __UNIQUE_ID(__x), __UNIQUE_ID(__y), op))

/**
 * min - return minimum of two values of the same or compatible types
 * @x: first value
 * @y: second value
 */
#define min(x, y)   __careful_cmp(x, y, <)

/**
 * max - return maximum of two values of the same or compatible types
 * @x: first value
 * @y: second value
 */
#define max(x, y)   __careful_cmp(x, y, >)

/**
 * min3 - return minimum of three values
 * @x: first value
 * @y: second value
 * @z: third value
 */
#define min3(x, y, z) min((typeof(x))min(x, y), z)

/**
 * max3 - return maximum of three values
 * @x: first value
 * @y: second value
 * @z: third value
 */
#define max3(x, y, z) max((typeof(x))max(x, y), z)
```

The C language itself has no appropriate way to handle this.

For lightweight projects, you can simply implement such a function for every type:

```
int min(int a, int b) {...}
short min(short a, short b) {...}
float min(float a, float b) {...}
...
```

Comment: How you would write a function to get the length of an string or an array in c?

Comment: As everyone knows, C strings are ended with a `'\0'`. Use `strlen()` to get their lengths. Some coders make all arrays end with a `NULL` object (e.g. `{"foo", "bar", "foo", NULL}`). Get their lengths as what `strlen()` does.